# Flutter + Firebase + Codemagic (without Mac)?

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, codemagic

So I wanted to make a Flutter Application with Android Studio, which worked out well for Android. But I'm broke (don't have a Mac) so when exporting for  IOS I wanted to make it over Codemagic.

So I wanted to ask: Is it possible to export my App to IOS using Codemagic but still using Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, yes. Check this [article](https://blog.codemagic.io/ios-code-signing-with-cli-tools/) for detail.

Comment: thanks
so firebase works, because there is nothing about firebase in the article

Comment: TBH, What's matter with firebase ?

Comment: Because I thought when adding a new IOS application it might add dificulties...

Comment: So far, I dont have any problem with it. At least you should do first, it wont bite anyway.

Comment: Yes there is a very specific issue to do with Firebase when you are building for iOS but don't have a Mac dev machine and that is you need to have Flutter run  as part of your build to be configured correctly for iOS on MacOS and then commit the config files generated to your git repo.

Comment: Actually I just tested this with the latest version of the Firebase core with Firestore plugin and Flutter Beta channel running on Codemagic and it seems that this is no longer an issue and Firebase builds fine even when the project is initially created on a non MacOS machine (I used Ubuntu)